# How to make 2 array dynamically and sent from jQuery to controller mvc core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a survey form view where I have a list view of all questions and below that we have score form 1-10 below every question now i want that when I rate all answers so that answers will go to controller with every question with their own id and then I will save that into DB so any best solution for this I searched a lot but didn't find anything ?

The solution I think we have to make 2 arrays dynamically one save id's of questions and other score of every question and then sent these 2 arrays to the controller is that okay or if anyone has a better solution for this so please let me know?

Comment: Why would you want to use jQuery? Why would you want to post an 2D array instead of your model? Just generate the view correctly so you model posts back to a POST method

Comment: i have a list view of questions and in that we have create view that store all value of selected scores for example we have 5 questions and user scores all 5 questions now i want to save all that 5 questions id and their respective scores into db what's best approach for this?

Comment: Read the last sentence in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON array that looks something like this:

```
var array = [
    { "id" : 1, "score" : 10},
    { "id" : 2, "score" : 1},
    { "id" : 3, "score" : 5}
];
```

That way you can store questions as objects and refer to them as array[index].property